# How to get latest rows with all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

When we use group by some column information is lost ,I am looking for a query such that all columns of the table is returned while getting the latest data.
Eg for following source data the expected result is all items quantity for latest date.

```
Data:
    Item    Quantity    Date
    Apple   7           7/17/2015
    Ball    15          7/17/2015
    Cat     10          7/17/2015
    Dog     8           7/19/2015
    Ball    1           7/19/2015



Desired Result:
    Item    Quantity    Date
    Apple   7           7/17/2015
    Ball    1           7/19/2015
    Cat     10          7/17/2015
    Dog     8           7/19/2015
```

Here if we use group by we loose the Quantity as it will be neither be in group by nor in aggregation.

This table does not have a id key so subquery could not be used.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `row_number()`:

```
select item, quantity, date
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```